# Access token for Google Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-authentication

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application that uses Google Authentication. The authentication part is working fine. But I am trying to find out how I can get hold of the access token for the login in my code so that I can pass it in the header for a web api that I have and wish to consume.

Comment: You can preserve access token to your database

Comment: Sure. But how do I get the access token in the first place.

Comment: Follow following link ,If feel any issue will provide the logical code :

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/?hl=en_GB

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use [Google's Sign-In button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) template to initialize the login & grant of permissions:

```html
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{{ OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID }}">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>

<div id="google-signin-button"
     class="g-signin2"
     data-width="170"
     data-height="30"
     data-onsuccess="onSignIn"
     data-onfailure="onSignInFailure">
</div>
```

```js
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var idToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
}
```

You can then pass the `idToken` (accessToken) to an API.